# How to change Chrome required field processing

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have some input fields with required attr

```
<input id="name" required="" placeholder="Write your name">
```

Additionally I have button that makes post back and some other link that makes postback as well.

But in case input field has't any data chrome block my post-back action, and show some chrome pupup box with information that I need to fill all data on form.
In the same time IE allows to do it.
How to resole it ?
of course I can remove this attribute with JavaScript before post-back action, but I am not sure this is right way.

Comment: Since ASP.Net has its own validation framework, browser support isn't 100%, and you need to validate on the server, I would probably just stick with ASP.Net validation for now and omit the `required` attribute.

Comment: correctly said by Tim Medora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't count on HTML5 `required` attribute since (in case of IE) only IE 10+ supports it (see "Form validation" section here: [Web Forms - Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)). Of course, the same goes for `placeholder` attribute but in most cases it's something you can live with (and having a working validation is more critical).

I think you should use the validation functionality provided by ASP.NET itself, it's very easy to get started with and you can easily make it work with and without JavaScript enabled on the client. More info here: [Understanding ASP.NET Validation Techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334310/Understanding-ASP-NET-Validation-Techniques).